# About downloading a file from a link html

Tags: html, dreamweaver, wampserver

I want to add a file to my website to be downloaded ,I am using html5, wampserver and dreamweaver.

I have used the following code (and it works fine):

```
 <a href="UploadFiles/MyFile.pdf" target="_blank">Program Download</a>
```

My question is:

I am working on localhost now but when I am gone put my website on line is there any changes?
eg: the address  of the file location http://.... or I will not change anything?

Answer (score 0):

If your html page is on the same level as your UploadFiles directory then you should be fine e.g.

index.html

UploadFiles/MyFile.pdf

I'd recommend using lower case filenames and directory names and it's generally best practice to do so and makes it easier to get paths etc correct.

The path you are using in your link is called a relative path but you could also use an absolue path which would look like this:

```
<a href="/UploadFiles/MyFile.pdf" target="_blank">Program Download</a>
```

The benefit of an absolute path is that it would work no matter where your html page is located within your file structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a relative link (that is, the first character isn't a slash, and doesn't start with `"http://"`), then everything should work the same on the server.